# What is the outer part of building called (figure)?

Tags: word-choice

What is the part of the building (usually skyscraper) extending out called?
It's the spot where superheroes are shown to be sitting when contemplating about their lives (looking down at the city).

For instance:

http://blog.frieze.com/uploads/blog/MID021A-03_thumb.jpg

http://www.uni.illinois.edu//og/media/archive/photos/2007/05/01/spiderman-3.jpg

I initially thought of **ledge** but I'm not sure this is the exact answer.

Comment: Those pictures are of two different things; what exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 6):

If you are talking about the smallish demi-wall at the top of many buildings, that's called a [parapet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parapet).

Answer (score 5):

The ornate carvings near the tops of older buildings are often called 'gargoyles.' In your first picture, she's sitting on top of a gargoyle. In the second, Spider Man is painted to look like a gargoyle. From the Shorter OED:

> A grotesque carving usu. in the form of a human or animal
>   mouth, head or body, projecting from the gutter of a building esp. in
>   Gothic architecture, and usu. acting as a spout to drain off
>   rainwater.

You might, however, simply mean "roof," "gutter" or as you suggest, "ledge."

Comment: I'm not looking at gargoyles per se (only spiderman does that) but all superheroes especially Batman.

Answer (score 3):

That architectural area is called the [**frieze**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frieze).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My teacher at school have been calling it [High Relief](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relief). He is a professional artist. So this is the word from artist point of view. I have heard it **gargoyles** as @JAM have mentioned.

Comment: A relief (high- or bas-) is a piece of sculpture, whereas OP is looking for the name of the part of a building.

Answer (score 1):

The decorative ledge which extends from a building's walls is a **cornice**. Here's a picture — the cornice might be right at the top, as here, or have a parapet or wall above it.

[image]

<sub>Image from http://jennyp12.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/architecture-glossary-a-to-z/</sub>